# How can I do an outer join with EF 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
 var tests = await db.Tests
            .Include(t => t.Exam)
            .Where(t => t.TestStatusId == 1)
            .Select(t => new TestDTO
            {
                ExamName = t.Exam.Name,
                Id = t.TestId,
                QuestionsCount = t.QuestionsCount,
                Title = t.Title
            })
            .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(tests);
```

How can I make this so that it still returns tests even if there is no matching Exam for a particular test?

Comment: How are you declaring Test and Exam? If Test.Exam is not marked as a required field, EF should use a left join on its own

Comment: Add `DefaultIfEmpty()` after `where`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//first step
    var tests = db.Tests
        .Include(t => t.Exam)
        .Where(t => t.TestStatusId == 1);

        //next step
        if(testc.Exam != null && testc.Exam.Count > 0)
        {
            testc = testc.Select(t => new TestDTO
        {
            ExamName = t.Exam.Name,
            Id = t.TestId,
            QuestionsCount = t.QuestionsCount,
            Title = t.Title
        });
        }
```